# How to eliminitate the first part of the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a property in my .cs file basically

```
public string MyURL
{
    get { return _myUrl; }
    set { _myURL = value; }
}
```

This property gets the value as a string ad it would something like this `www.shipco.com`.

The issue I am having is when i putting it in the page as an anchor with target blank it gives it as a location in the website like `http://mywebsite/www.shipco.com`

This is how I am setting it on the page:

```
     <div>
 <strong>URL :</strong> 
          <a href="<%=MyURL%>" target="_blank"><%=MyURL%></a>  
    </div>
```

I would appreciate any help as I am learning and not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basics of fully qualified URLs and relative URLs in the browser:

```
<a href="www.shipco.com" target="_blank">www.shipco.com</a>
```

The above means, go to the current URL, only replace the current page path with the `href`. You will see that the source of the page is exactly what you expect it to be. The browser interprets it as a relative location to the current page - it doesn't "know" it is a different website.

You need to output the `http://` as well:

```
<a href="http://<%=MyURL%>" target="_blank"><%=MyURL%></a>
```

Perhaps [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm) About.com article will shed some light.